# How to use better driver (nouveau) instead of generic VESA with NVIDIA Quadro NVS 140M?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, gnome-shell

I've got [laptop](http://www.afterdawn.com/products/product_details.cfm/3297/lenovo_thinkpad_r61_89185wg) with NVIDIA Quadro NVS 140M and have no Gnome-shell which I like very well.
I use:

> Debian GNU/Linux jessie /sid \n \l

When I run Debian as live USB everything works fine.

How to get gnome3-shell instead of failback?
I've tried to replace dir

```
/etc/X11
```

with the one from live USB but this fails.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` installed?

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture to guess that because the Nvidia card is a mobile one it uses [Nvidia Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) technology. (I did not confirm this for your exact card)

However, I have had this same issue with Gnome 3 going back to fallback (in Fedora) if I didn't properly have the open source solution for optimus on my laptop, an issue that can be solved with **[BumbleBee](http://bumblebee-project.org/).**

...And some notes [from your distro's wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee).